# How to extract the .img file into normal kernel source file in the linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Currently, I've a .img file (Kernel source file) with a capacity of 3.7GB. Could you Please suggest Linux terminal commands for extracting this .img file into a normal kernel source file?

Thanks & Regards

Ravikumar

Comment: If the .img file is a raw disk image, try `udisksctl loop-setup -f file.img`. That will create /dev/loopX and if the image contains partitions, /dev/loopXpY for each partition. Then use `udisksctl mount -b /dev/loopXpY` to mount the partition. Use `udisksctl loop-delete -b /dev/loopX` to delete the loopback block devices created by `loop-setup`.